# How to give a prop a parameter vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

So I am trying to use vue-sidebar-menu and and figure out how to pass arguments for the props that it gives. I've tried a variety of different ways but cannot seem to find one that will allow me to collapse the navbar when the page is loaded. There is a property that is called collapsed however I cannot seem to figure out how to pass it this prop when the page is loaded to keep the navigation bar collapsed.

Some of the template looks like this

```
export default {
  name: 'SidebarMenu',
  components: {
    Item,
    SubItem,
    MobileItem
  },
  props: {
    menu: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    collapsed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: '350px'
    },
    widthCollapsed: {
      type: String,
      default: '50px'
    }
```

With that my code for implementing of the navbar looks like this

```
<template>
  <sidebar-menu :menu="menu" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        collapsed: true,
        menu: [
          {
            header: true,
            title: 'Main Navigation'
            // component: componentName
            // visibleOnCollapse: true
          },
          {
            href: '/',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'fa fa-user'
            /*
            disabled: true
            badge: {
            text: 'new',
            // class:''
          }
          */
          },
          {
            title: 'Other',
            icon: 'fa fa-chart-area',
            child: [
              {
                href: '/charts/sublink',
                title: 'Sub Link'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

With my code I tried a bunch of different way to give it the collapse variable but I feel like I do not have a full grasp on vue props if someone could help me out I've looked through the docs for vue on this topic and haven't found anything to helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually when you get such question, you can take a quick look at the [package source code.](https://github.com/yaminncco/vue-sidebar-menu/blob/master/src/components/SidebarMenu.vue)

the `collapsed` prop accepts a boolean value. your parent component will look like:

```
<template>
  <sidebar-menu :menu="menu" :collapsed="myCollapse"/>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        myCollapse:false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

then, every time you change your own `mycollapse` property, the sidebar-menu component will react to that change.

Comment: Worked Perfect Thank you. I guess I just misunderstood the way that components accept props.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would need to pass the collapsed value as a prop to the sidebar-menu

```
<sidebar-menu :menu="menu" :collapsed="collapsed"/>
```

if that doesn't help adding some more code to make the example clearer would be better.